# Creating transparent shapes on images in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

In Visio I need to put shapes on a map (image).  I am trying to put circles around cities on a map, but the circle covers the map content. How do I put make this circle transparent, allowing the content in within the circle to be seen?

Answer (score 2):

In Visio 2016 (See `File/Account` and then click on `About Visio` to check this) you have a way to modify most picture attributes - including transparency -  through the `Format Ribbon`:

[image]

Which brings up this:

[image]

Posting it here because it took me ages to find. This `Format Picture` dialog should obviously be an option when you right click a picture, but somehow they forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

The exact menu details depend upon your version of Visio.

Select the circle shape and

**Home** -> **Fill** -> **Fill Options** and set the transparency
or
right-click -> **Format** -> **Fill** -> **Fill Options** and set the transparency.